# How to display update message only to admin

Tags: multisite, network-admin, options

How can I show the update message only to super admin in the network wordpress ? I don't want the other admins/users see the update message that shows the current version.
Is there any plugin to do this or I have to changes the core?

Comment: -1 for "change the core"... Also, plugin recommendation is off-topic now, as per the new FAQ... *"Anyone knows which hooks can do this?"* is the way to go :) - Nice snippet by Mridul!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own plugin with this code or put this in theme's functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'remove_update_notification', 1)
function remove_update_notification() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_network')) { // checks to see if current user can update plugins 
        add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
        add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems it doesn't know get_currentuserinfo(); fatal error is returned.

Comment: if that function is unavailable then wrapping the function in a hook will help. updated the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Lower the level of those users to `Editor` as the users you are referring to are probably not meant to be administrators. That will degrade some other stuff they can do too, like creating/editing users, managing plugins, managing themes, etc. You can read more on [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).